# Mantener datos en Formulario después de enviar

Tags: php, jquery

estoy enviando un formulario a travez de JQuery con la siguiente funcion

```
$('#btnEnviarDatosComputadora').click( function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'forms/Equipo/registrar.php',
        type: 'post',       
        data: $('form#SubirDatosComputadora').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#response').html('<strong>Datos Guardados!</strong>');
        },
        error: function(){
                alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

tengo el div

```
<div id="response"></div>
```

donde aparecera mi mensaje...

pero al momento de hacer el submit, aparece el mensaje por 1 segundo y se recarga la pagina borrando los datos del formulario.
mi form

```
<form id="SubirDatosComputadora" name="SubirDatosComputadora" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

mi boton

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btnEnviarDatosComputadora" id="btnEnviarDatosComputadora" value="Enviar Datos">
```

Comment: Podés mostrar un poco más el formulario? Parece ser que el botón tiene asignado el submit.

Comment: listo! agrege mi form y mi boton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que al hacer click en el botón, tenés asignado el `type="submit"`, entonces va a hacer submit del formulario por más que le pongas el evento, entonces la solución es usar [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) y así evitar que se haga submit y refresque la página.

```
$('#btnEnviarDatosComputadora').click(function(event){
    // prevengo la propagación del submit
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'forms/Equipo/registrar.php',
        type: 'post',       
        data: $('form#SubirDatosComputadora').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#response').html('<strong>Datos Guardados!</strong>');
        },
        error: function(){
                alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Otra posible solución es cambiar el `type="submit"` del botón por `type="button"`, entonces esto no hace submit del formulario.

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="btnEnviarDatosComputadora" id="btnEnviarDatosComputadora" value="Enviar Datos">
```

Comment: Gracias! es la solucion!

Comment: No hay problema Willy!

Answer (score 1):

Inténtalo así:

Con el preventDefalt se evita que se ejecute lo que viene por defecto del navegador, que es procesar el formulario.

```
$('#btnEnviarDatosComputadora').click(function(e){ 
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
        url: 'forms/Equipo/registrar.php',
        type: 'post',       
        data: $('form#SubirDatosComputadora').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#response').html('Datos Guardados!');
        },
        error: function(){
                alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Explica al menos para que sirve `preventDefault`, de modo que el OP entienda  la solución que estás sugiriendo.

Comment: Soy malo explicando xD, pero ya esta!